# word-break:break-all CSS Property

Tags: css, word-break

```
div class="panel-footer" style="line-height:30px;overflow:auto;word-break: break-all;word-spacing:2px; hyphens: auto;"
```

Word-break property of CSS is not showing text in a proper manner.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is and fix your code to be a slightly more complete example? `word-break: break-all` causes text to break at *any character*, which is what *seems* to be happening in your image, however I can't be certain because I'm not familiar with the characters.

Comment: Actually when I am trying to give property align: justify then it is showing more spaces between words. So I want to remove extra spaces between words. When I tried word-break it removed extra spaces but it is not showing text in a proper manner. You can see image for this